# How to plot a scatter plot and a line plot as a subplot in one plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following codes:

**For scatter plot:**

```
plt.scatter(x_1.values[y_ocsvm1 == 1, 2], scaled_array[y_ocsvm1 == 1, 0], c = 'red', label = 'cluster1')
plt.scatter(x_1.values[y_ocsvm1 == -1, 2], scaled_array[y_ocsvm1 == -1, 0], c = 'blue', label = 'cluster2')
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
plt.yticks(np.arange(min(scaled_array[:,[0]]), max(scaled_array[:,[0]]), 0.05))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This gives me:
[image]

**For line plot:**

```
plt.plot(x, y)
```

This gives me:

[image]

I would like to plot both these two as subplots in the same plot (Vertically stacked plots).

I would like to know how can this be done

Thanks

**Edit:**

I tried doing:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax2.plot(plt.scatter(x_1.values[y_ocsvm1 == 1, 2], scaled_array[y_ocsvm1 == 1, 0], c = 'red', label = 'cluster1')
, plt.scatter(x_1.values[y_ocsvm1 == -1, 2], scaled_array[y_ocsvm1 == -1, 0], c = 'blue', label = 'cluster2'))
```

And it gives me the desired plot as follows:
[image]

But it also shows the following error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'PathCollection'
```

Comment: What is the problem right now you facing? Putting these commands next to each other will plot the line and the scatter in the same plot.Tell us what is not working

Comment: I don't want them in one single plot. I want them as 2 different plots in one subplot

Comment: You are using wrong terminology. What you actually need is a single figure with two subplots: One subplot for the line and the other subplot for the scatter. I am marking this as a duplicate. There are several answers on how to do this

Comment: Also, it is not clear what you mean by "one top of the other.". Does it mean upper figure with scatter and lower figure with line like a 2 row 1 column figure? "one top of the other." usually means scatter points on the top of line which means the same figure. Sometimes, it is better to include a sample hand sketched figure in your question in order of better explaining.

Comment: Try reading the [official](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html) examples

Comment: I will edit my question and include the graphs as well.

Comment: @Sheldore I have updated my question

Comment: This is explained in the official example I linked. Plz read them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)

ax1.plot(x, y)

ax2.scatter(x_1.values[y_ocsvm1 == 1, 2], scaled_array[y_ocsvm1 == 1, 0], 
            color='red', label='cluster1')
ax2.scatter(x_1.values[y_ocsvm1 == -1, 2], scaled_array[y_ocsvm1 == -1, 0], 
            color='blue', label='cluster2')

plt.legend() # To show the legend
```